# Not able to extract data from an api package in R called Rdota2

Tags: r, dataframe

I am not able to access a function in a package of R. The function name is `get_league_listing` and the package name is `Rdota2`. It displays the following error:

```
Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())  : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

This was the command used:

```
get_league_listing(dota_id = 570, language = "en", key = NULL)
```

Please help me out.

Comment: Are you certain that id 570 contains (correct) data? [The source](https://github.com/LyzandeR/RDota2/blob/master/R/get_league_listing.R#L44) is using `rbind.data.frame` (which produces that error), so this suggests that `dota_result$content` (internal) is different or empty. I suggest you `debugonce(get_league_listing)`, repeat your call, then step until `dota_result` is created and take a look at it. That variable should have fields [`"content", "url", and "response"](https://github.com/LyzandeR/RDota2/blob/b66dd186bcc85491008e263ef326a37e7b894816/R/core.R#L81-L88).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This used to return a data.frame, but Valve decided that one of the leagues should not have a description field, which makes the `rbind` part of the code (as @r2evans correctly mentions in the comments) below fail (code from `get_league_listing`), due to the different number of columns:

```
args <- list(key = key, language = 'en')
dota_result <- get_response(570, 'GetLeagueListing', 'IDOTA2Match', 1, args)
#the below fails
dota_result$content <-
  do.call(rbind.data.frame, c(dota_result$content[[1]][[1]], stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
Error in (function (..., deparse.level = 1, make.row.names = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())  : 
  numbers of columns of arguments do not match
```

This is the culprit btw (there should be a description element here in order for `rbind` to work):

```
> dota_result$content[[1]][[1]][[1651]]
$name
[1] "The International 2017 Open Qualifiers"

$leagueid
[1] 5498

$tournament_url
[1] "http://www.dota2.com"

$itemdef
[1] 17377
```

The solution, until I update the package, is to use the response and then probably data.table to convert to a data.frame / data.table:

```
library(data.table)
#if your key is stored using the method described at the vignette
#leave it as NULL, otherwise add your key.
args <- list(key = key, language = 'en')
dota_result <- get_response(570, 'GetLeagueListing', 'IDOTA2Match', 1, args)
rbindlist(dota_result$content[[1]][[1]], fill = TRUE, use.names = TRUE)
```

which will return:

```
                                         name leagueid
   1:                     Dota 2 Just For Fun     1212
   2:                joinDOTA League Season 3     1640
   3:            Killing Spree: North America       25
   4:                         Wild Cards West        2
   5:                         Wild Cards East        3
  ---                                                 
1683:                          GESC: Thailand     9663
1684:          Dota 2 Asia Championships 2018     9643
1685:                    ESL One Genting 2018     8093
1686:            Corsair DreamLeague season 9     9683
1687: StarLadder ImbaTV Invitational Season 5     9908
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          description
   1:                                                                                                                                                                               64 of the best Brazilian amateur teams compete to become the winner of the first Dota 2 Just For Fun tournament. 
   2:               The global Dota 2 league for everyone. Featured are all of the matches from division 1 and 2. There are three leagues: Europe, America, and Asia. The top 10 from each league meet in the premier division. $1.00 from each ticket purchased will go directly into the prizepool.
```